# Issue with downloading file express.js

Tags: node.js, express, download, google-drive-api

I have been trying to download file from Google drive api using express.js
So I have been getting file stream from Drive and sending it in response. I am also setting content-disposition:attachment, fileName and Content-type.
When I am testing this route using fiddler it is showing the content type and fileName. But when called in browser it downloads the files but does not set the fileName and its extension.
E.g: MineType is image/jpeg and it is downloading the file as jfif format with random name.
Some help will be really appreciated. Thanks
Following are the code snippets I am using

```js
function downloadFile(auth,fileId){
  return new Promise((success,failure)=>{
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    drive.files.get({
      fileId:fileId,
      alt:'media'
    },
    (err,res)=>{
      if(err)
        return failure("Unable to download file");
      return success(res.data);
    });
    
  });
}
```

```js
app.get('/DownloadFile/:id',function(req,res){
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
 Drive.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH)
 .then((credentials)=>{ 
  readTokens() //will call db.readTokens here
  .then((returnObj)=>{
   token=returnObj.token;
   refreshToken=returnObj.refreshToken;
   Drive.createAuthOjectWithTokenRefresh(credentials,token,refreshToken)
   .then((oAuth2Client)=>{
    Drive.getFileDetails(oAuth2Client,req.params.id)
    .then((details)=>{
     res.header("Content-Disposition","attachment");
     res.header("filename",details.name);
     res.header("Content-Type",details.mimeType);
     Drive.downloadFile(oAuth2Client,req.params.id)
     .then((file)=>{
      res.send(file);
      res.end();
     })
     .catch((err)=>{
      res.end(err.message);
     });
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
     res.end(err.message);
    });
   })
   .catch((err)=>{
    res.end(err.message);
   });
   
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
   res.redirect("/Authenticate");
   res.end();
  });
 })
 .catch((err)=>{
  res.redirect(err);
 });
})
```

Comment: Have you checked this same [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1024) in github?

Comment: Yeah I have checked but couldn't find any help. But after a lot of testing found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing and brainstorming found the issue. So Google Drive Api sends the file data in JSON string format. When sent as string it losses most of the characters and the file gets corrupted. Found that Get functions receives an optional parameter named responseType which can receive 'arraybuffer', 'blob', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream' as value. This optional parameter is not documented in the drive api.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

What worked for me:

```
drive.files.get({
  fileId:fileId,
  alt:'media'
},{
  responseType:'arraybuffer'
},
(err,res)=>{
  if(err)
    return failure("Unable to download file");
  return success(res.data);
});
```